# close browser window using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have implemented cron job for sending mail to customer in Windows 7. I would like to close the browser window on server after specific period of time.

The below HTML file contains Javascript in which I have used `window.close()`. This function is used to close the window but it only refreshes the browser page and does not close the window.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Open/Close Window</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function CloseWindow() {
            window.close();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
        <%--<input type="button" value="Open 'myWindow'" onclick="openWin()">
    <input type="button" value="Close 'myWindow'" onclick="closeWin()">--%>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have called the Javascript function on page load event of `.cs` file. The below code refreshes the page but does not close the window.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(typeof(Page), "closePage", "window.onunload = CloseWindow();");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `self.close()` instead.
You could read [this](http://javascript.about.com/library/blclose.htm) to get a better idea.

Hope I helped!